# Apollo Client not querying custom scalar types

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I've made a datasource API to fetch an external API and retrieve it in JSON format. Everything works perfectly, I can call the query in playground and get all the data.

But when I call that query from the react / apollo client side, the data from the query is always returning null. I'm guessing it has something to do with the scalar type.

Apollo Client Query

```
// Drops
export const GET_DROPS = gql`
    query getDrops {
        getDrops
    }
`;
```

Drop Resolver (Server)

```
import GraphQLJSON from 'graphql-type-json';

export default {
    JSON: GraphQLJSON,
    Query: {
        getDrops: async (_source, _args, { dataSources }) => {
            const data = await dataSources.dropsAPI.fetchDrops();
            return data.result.data;
        }
    }
};
```

Drop Schema

```
export default gql`
    scalar JSON

    extend type Query {
        getDrops: JSON
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apollo Client doesn't currently support custom scalar serialization on the client side at the moment. We do have an [older feature request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8857)t to add better support for them and are considering this for a future enhancement to our client library.

Feel free to follow this Github issue if you are interested in this capability, also adding a comment about your use case will help us better understand your needs as well. Thank you!